# "Invalid character" error message when serializing/deserializing a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the function below to "clone" an object.  Occasionally we see an "Invalid character" error message displayed in the browser's console.  Based on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for the `JSON` object, this function should work flawlessly.  I also checked, and the objects being serialized do not implement the [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) function.  What kind of object(s) would cause this error?

```js
function deepCopy (obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

**Update:** It appears to only happen with IE11.

Comment: If you want to parse to json use only `JSON.parse` no need of `JSON.stringify`

Comment: what is the value of `obj`?

Comment: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/122102)

Comment: Do you have dates in that object?

Comment: `deepCopy({@_23:"sdfs"})` , should give error, basically objects with not a valid variable key will give error. JavaScript object not JSON,

Comment: Maybe append the object that gives this error in your case and someone might explain why it break,

Comment: `JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns undefined instead of a string. That might be it.

Comment: I actually do not know what the data is.  My system logs JS error but because this object could contain user data we cannot log it.  It may have dates in it.

Comment: Turns out it was `undefined` being passed in.  Thank you @JacqueGoupil

Comment: Oh, glad I helped :) Then might as well post it as a detailed answer so you can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns `undefined` instead of the string "undefined". As seen on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> JSON.stringify can also just return undefined when passing in "pure"
>   values like `JSON.stringify(function(){})` or `JSON.stringify(undefined)`.

JSON.parse has some unclear error messages when it receives a non-serializable object because it will try to convert this object into a string first. I once lost a lot of time on this one in Chrome : `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`.

That's because u is the first letter of `undefined` converted to a string. A similar error comes up when trying to parse an object, which gives the string "[object Object]" with a valid opening bracket but an *unexpected token o* afterward. It's good to keep those cases in mind.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it happens if the value contains `'` character.

So, please clean especial character, another way is converting into utf-8, before stringify.

That way, I solved my problem earlier.

Comment: Which way would you recommend converting to "utf-8"?

Comment: what is the value of obj?

Comment: suppose 
var a = {};
a = {key: "val'ue"}

either you can remove ' from val'ue or you can convert the value, function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}
//decode
function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}